# A better way to find a module's children?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

This is what I've got, but it also finds classes and other constants.. is there a better way?

```
class Module
    def children
        constants.collect { |c| const_get(c) }.compact
    end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By 'children' you seem to mean modules nested under a given module, right? Nothing to do with inheritance relationships?

Assuming you just mean nested modules, the following should work:

```
class Module
    def children
        constants.collect { |c| const_get(c) }.
            select { |m| m.instance_of?(Module) }
    end
end
```

**EDIT:** You may need to use `constants(false)` to prevent constant look-up on modules further up the inheritance chain.